# Reporting the results of nonparametric regression using kernel weights

Tags: r, nonparametric, reporting, nonparametric-regression

I am wondering how I can present the results of nonparametric regression. I performed the nonparametric tests using R, and R package `np`.

The commands used for this are

```r
 freq <- npreg(Respno ~ Colony + Localden + Agg.prop,
               regtype = "ll",
               bwmethod = "cv.aic",
               gradients = TRUE,
               data = resp)

 summary(freq2)

 npsigtest(freq2)
```

Using the last command, `npsigtest`, I get results like this

```r
npsigtest(freq)

Kernel Regression Significance Test
Type I Test with IID Bootstrap (399 replications, Pivot = TRUE, joint = FALSE)

Explanatory variables tested for significance:

Colony (1), Localden (2), Agg.prop (3)


Colony Localden Agg.prop

Bandwidth(s): 21.88052 5956578 0.3183519

Individual Significance Tests

P Value: 

Colony 0.0025063 ** 

Localden < 2.22e-16 *** 

Agg.prop 0.0802005
```

How do I present this data in a scientific paper? For the simple linear regression results, I included the `n`, `df`, `t` and `P`.

Comment: I have the same your problem about reporting the results of nonparametric regression I also used kernel Analysis. How did you solve? Thanks

Comment: @al9 please do not use answers for commenting the questions. Answers are meant for answering questions. When you gain more reputation you'd be able to comment the questions.

Comment: Have you actually read any studies publishing the results of nonparametric regressions? You might take a cue, especially from ones in your own discipline, and, if there are any, ones using the same specific method you are using.

Comment: Look for published examples of nonparametric regression in your own discipline's major journal(s) to get a sense of conventions for reporting.

Answer (score 0):

For presentation you should be clear that **Why are you doing this?** If you want to calculate residuals ($y-\hat{y}$), then use `residuals(freq)`and accordingly you can use these to calculate MSE. Here three bandwidths are used respective to your covariates.